# How to wait scheduled future with flutter_test?

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

My widget execute an asynchronous task and I want to check whether it is complete or not.

But it seems widget tester terminates the test before the task is executed. Whole code is [here](https://github.com/jeiea/flutter_example/tree/test-async).

```dart
class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    test();
  }

  Stream<int?> stream(Future<void> Function() worker) async* {
    Stream<int?> work() async* {
      await worker();
      yield 3;
    }

    yield* work();
  }

  Future<void> sampleWorker() async {
    throw Error();
  }

  Future<void> test() async {
    print('start');
    try {
      await for (final v in stream(sampleWorker)) {
        print(v);
      }
      print('point 1');
    } catch (error, stack) {
      print(stack);
    }
    print('done');
  }
}

void main() {
  testWidgets('Widget test', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    // Build our app and trigger a frame.
    await tester.pumpWidget(MyApp());
    await tester.pumpAndSettle(const Duration(milliseconds: 1000));
  });

  test('Plain test', () async {
    await MyHomePageState().test();
  });
}
```

I want both tests print stack trace, but only 'Plain test' shows expected behavior. The following is the log.

```
start
✓ Widget test
start
#0      MyHomePageState.sampleWorker (package:bug_report/main.dart:48:5)
#1      MyHomePageState.stream.work (package:bug_report/main.dart:40:19)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      StackZoneSpecification._registerUnaryCallback.<anonymous closure> (package:stack_trace/src/stack_zone_specification.dart)
<asynchronous suspension>

done
✓ Plain test
```

How to make first test prints stack trace? I should not await `test()` because it should be widget's internal task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `WidgetTester`'s `runAsync` function to await an arbitrary amount of time for an internal widget's async task to complete.